# Why is my app crashing when I get decimal input type value from edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, double

I'm trying to get text from `EditText` with decimal input type
It works fine but when I use `double value =Double.parseDouble(valueString);` It causes the app crashing'

I'm using it in that form :

```
Editable valueEditable = edtTxt1.getText();
String valueString = valueEditable.toString();
double value =  Double.parseDouble(valueString);
```

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.fatima.convertionsbetweenhourspersentagesadayaweek.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:45)

Comment: So `valueString` is empty.  If you don't expect that we need a bit more code to see why it's empty.  Otherwise, you need to check for that before trying to do the `parseDouble`.

Comment: Okay I knew now that the problem is that the getText is in the on create level, so the editText still have no value....so how can I put the edit text in place that I will be sure to have a value inside the text before I do the gettext.............. I'm sorry but I'm new in stackover flow so I tried to put all the code but it doesn't fit in here

Comment: Ideally you should call getText() either when user click a button or onTextChangeListerner  of  edittext

Comment: I'm using it inside onItemSelected